# Track functional dependencies in R

Tags: r

Is there a way how I can analyze programatically what functions are called inside another function? Let's say I have a package with functions:

```
a <- function(c, d) c + d
b <- function(e, f) e + f

x <- function(g, h) {
     c(
       a(g - h, g + h),
       b(g * h, g / h)
       )
     }
```

Is there something like `analyzeFunction(x)` what would return `a` and `b` (functions called from `x`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codetools::findGlobals()` does basically what you're asking for, though it returns *all* of the functions directly called by `x()`:

```
library(codeTools)
findGlobals(x)
# [1] "-" "*" "/" "{" "+" "a" "b" "c"
```

If you'd like to winnow down the results to only view functions that are in `.GlobalEnv`, say, or only those that are defined outside of a package, you can do something like this

```
vv <- findGlobals(x)
intersect(vv, ls(.GlobalEnv))
# [1] "a" "b"
vv[!grepl("package|namespace", sapply(vv, find))]
# [1] "a" "b"
```